# GFForms class doesn't exist (even though Gravity forms is installed)

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Inside my plugin, I have this line:

```
if (class_exists("GFForms")) { //...
```

Based on my debug logs, `class_exists("GFForms")` returns false on a new client's site.
It worked on a few other sites just fine.

Gravity forms plugin (which is supposed to contain GFForms class) is installed and activated.

Gravity forms version is 2.2.1.

What could be causing this problem on a new client's website? (which has Multi-site installed if that makes any difference; my plugin is network-activated by the way)

Comment: Could you show me some of your code above your if statement? Because this should work fine if you just installed gf and activated it.